# Displaying an image and a text with Spring MVC (from database)

Tags: java, image, spring, jsp

I want to display an image **AND** a String using Spring MVC 3.
Both are instance variables of a POJO that I retreive from the database using Hibernate.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
public class Document {

    //id        

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;  // the String

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name="content")
    private byte [] image;
//getters setters
```

I want to display the image on the .jsp page using Spring MVC 3 **AND** display the String next to it.
Currently I can display **ONLY** the picture by streaming it and printing the String to the console but it is not what I want. (Of course I can display the String, but if I display the String, then I am not able to display the image.) **I want to display both,** on the same page, next to eachother.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/displayDocument", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void displayDocument(@RequestParam("documentId") String documentId, HttpServletResponse response) {

        Document doc = documentService.get(Long.valueOf(documentId));

        System.out.println(doc.getName());

        if (doc.getImage() != null) {
            response.setContentType("image/jpg");
            try {
                response.getOutputStream().write(doc.getImage());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
                response.getOutputStream().close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

I do not want to beleive that there isn't any clever solution to acheive this....

Comment: I think you are a bit misstaken about how http works. Images are always fetched in a seperate request. So basicly, you want to construct a JSP page where you display the name, together with an img tag with /displayDocument as src, where you serve the image. You will need to do two seperate db fetches for this since it will be different threads.

Comment: I'm gonna try this out tomorrow but I am afraid if I do that than the user has to click the img link in order to see the picture, (ie the images won't appear automatically), am I correct or absolutely mistaken?

Comment: You are mistaken, web browsers will automatically fetch the HTML file from the URL, then fetch all resources linked in that HTML file. This include CSS, JS, images and similar. This is how the web works, and the standard solution.

Comment: OK, I got what you mean. It works. Now I would recommend to copy-paste your comment and publish it as answer and then I can accept it, because basically it was you suggestion that helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: Posted as a proper answer (if a bit short)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are a bit mistaken about how http protocol works. Images are always fetched in a seperate request by the web browser automatically (this also goes for `<script>`, `<style>`, `<img>` and some other tags).
 So basicly, you want to construct a JSP page where you display the name, together with

`<img src="/viewimage?id=${theDocumentId}"/>`.

viewimage might be a servlet where you serve the image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused at what you want to accomplish here as your question first refers to a JSP page but you are writing the image directly to the output stream in your Controller.

The way I would handle something like this with Spring MVC would be, on a request to the main page for this "document", to add the attributes of the document to the Model so your view layer can output it, and include a link in the HTML containing the documentID to a controller which can render an image in response to a request (since you can't exactly render an image within the output of a JSP page - an HTML document).

It looks like you are on the right track to the second half of this, but there aren't enough details given to give you advice on the first part.

Comment: _your question first refers to JSP page but you are writing the image directly to the output stream in your Controller._ I am doing this not because it is the best solution I can imagine rather this is the only "solution" I can do. In a perfect world I would rather do that: 
**model.addAttribute("document",documentService.get(Long.valueOf(documentId));** and on the jsp page I would just take out the name like this:  **Documents name: ${document.name}** and the image like this **Image: ${document.image}** But  because it is not possible to do it in the easy way, hence the confusion.

Comment: The only way it would be possible is if you wrote some javascript in the view that would render the image `byte[]` with a [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to an `img` tag. The difficulty you have here is that you have a `byte[]` of data you need to get into the img tag - the traditional way is to just set the img src to a URL. It's not a problem of Spring or Java, but of the HTML document.

Comment: I got it and thanks. But I would rather accept  Rasmus Franke's comment when it is going to be republished as an answer, not because it is more accurate or better but because it was more digestable for me. Nevertheless, I wanna vote your answer as useful, too

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

Add the `@ResponseBody` annotation on `displayDocument()` method